# Multithreading with a Vector of different functions

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am trying to run multiple functions on different threads. I wrote this (minimal) code that works

```rust
use std::thread;

fn f1(count: usize) {
    for i in 0..count { /*do something*/ }
}

fn f2(count: usize) {
    for i in 0..count { /*do something*/ }
}

fn run(ops: &Vec<impl Fn(usize) + Sync + Send + Copy + 'static>) {
    for i in 0..ops.len() {
        let func = ops[i];
        thread::spawn(move || func(1000));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ops = vec![f1, f1]; // putting the same function twice
    run(&ops);
}
```

However, as soon as I send different functions

```rust
    let ops = vec![f1, f2];
```

Compiling fails. As I understand it, I cannot hold different types in the same vector (I guess, functions have different memory requirements, though I'm not quite sure how function pointers work).

I tried browsing similar questions on SO, and I tried this solution

```rust
    let ops: Vec<&dyn Fn(usize)> = vec![&f1, &f2];
```

and I get this error

```
`dyn Fn(usize)` cannot be shared between threads safely
the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `dyn Fn(usize)`
```

And I'm stuck as I'm struggling to understand the base issue. Do you have insights on how I should understand this problem, and any pointers on how to solve it ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as you can add the `Sync` marker with `impl`, you can also add it with `&dyn`, but you may need parenthesis to disambiguate:

```
fn run(ops: &Vec<&'static (dyn Fn(usize) + Sync)>)
```

Two minor comments:

- Generally, using `&[…]` instead of `&Vec<…>` is more flexible and to be preferred.
- No need to do `for i in 0…foos.len()` in rust, `for foo in foos` will do fine. (You may occasionally have to use `for foo in &foos` or `for foo in foos.iter()`. If you do need the index, `.enumerate()` is convenient.)
- If the `'static` is a bother (e.g. because you want to pass in some closure that captures local variables and can't be `'static`), you could either use scoped threads ([example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b2633c0458d5d75135ef783aecaf8a27)), or pass owned `Fn`s as `Vec<Box<dyn Fn(usize) + Sync>>`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, it was just a question of adding `Sync`. Thanks a lot too for your additionnal recommendations!